# How to prove semi open feebly propety in topological subspace?

Tags: general-topology

> **Theorem 16**: Let $(Y,T_Y)$ be a subspace of topological space $(X,T)$ such that $Y$ semi feebly open in $X$ then $u$ is semi feebly open in $Y$ if and only if $\exists v$ semi feebly open in $X$ such that $u=v\cap Y$.

> **Definition**: Let $A\subseteq X$. Then $A$ is called semi feebly open set in $X$ if $A \subseteq U$ where $U$ is semi open set then $\overline{A}^f\subseteq U$.

> **Definition**: $A$ is called semi open set in $X$ if there exists an open set $O$ such that $O\subseteq A\subseteq \overline{O}$.

> **Definition**: $A$ is called feebly open set in $X$ if there exists an open set $O$ such that $O\subseteq A\subseteq \overline{O}^s$.

> **Remark**: $A\subseteq X$ is called feebly open set in $X$ if and only if $A\subseteq \overline{A^\circ}^\circ$ and feebly closed if $\overline{\overline{A}^\circ}\subseteq A$.

> **Definition**: The interesction of all closed subsets containing $A\subseteq X$ is called semi closure of $A$ and is donated by $\overline{A}^s$.

> **Definition**: The interesction of all feebly closed subsets containing $A\subseteq X$ is donated by $\overline{A}^f$.

My professor wrote **Theorem 16** without proving it. He said the proof is not required. However just for curiosity I searched for a proof and couldn't find any. Is there a way to proof this theorem?

Comment: What do you mean by "semi open set". Also, I assume that by $\bar{A}$ you want to mean the closure of $A$ but, What is the meaning of the symbol $f$ in your notation?

Comment: @Gödel, I have updated my question. $\overline{A}$ means the closure of $A$ , $f$ means feebly and $s$ means semi.